# Mutate function not a double vector error

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried to create a new column State with values: when Region matches the values of states, fill the corresponding values of Region. But it shows an error.

My code is as shown below here:

```
states_trips <- qtr_full %>%
  mutate(State = case_when(Region %in% states ~ Region , TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

[image: preview 1]

[image: preview 2]

[image: preview 3]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), including the section saying *DO NOT post images of code*. Please copy and paste instead, and edit the question to include details.

Comment: This looks like R, it would be good to add a tag for the language as well (to help find people who can answer this).

Answer (score 1):

Example with modified data: have put matching `states` to `Region`
Note: this is for exact match:

#### `case_when` or `ifelse`

```
library(dplyr)
# case_when
states_trips <- qtr_full %>%
  mutate(State = case_when(Region %in% states ~ Region,
                           TRUE ~ "NA"))

# or

# ifelse
states_trips <- qtr_full %>%
  mutate(State = ifelse(Region %in% states, Region, NA))
```

Output:

```
   Quarter            Region             Holiday Visiting Business  Other State          
   <chr>              <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>          
 1 March quarter 1... Sydney               828      818      525   117    NA             
 2 March quarter 1... Tasmania             104       70.5     18.8   2.48 Tasmania       
 3 March quarter 1... Capital Country       99.2    100       42.7  19.9  NA             
 4 March quarter 1... Central Coast        279      149       24.2   2.93 NA             
 5 March quarter 1... New South Wales      170      143       99.8  11.7  New South Wales
 6 March quarter 1... Hunter               329      266       69.2  10.8  NA             
 7 March quarter 1... New England Nort..   115      143       60.3  11.7  NA             
 8 March quarter 1... North Coast NSW      828      416       55.4  42.4  NA             
 9 March quarter 1... Outback NSW           24.5     21.3     48.7   2.07 NA             
10 March quarter 1... Victoria              46.5     71.8     82.4  14.6  Victoria
```

data:

```
qtr_full <- tibble::tribble(
                          ~Quarter, ~Region, ~Holiday, ~Visiting, ~Business, ~Other,
              "March quarter 1...", "Sydney",      828,       818,       525,    117,
      "March quarter 1...", "Tasmania",      104,      70.5,      18.8,   2.48,
     "March quarter 1...", "Capital Country",     99.2,       100,      42.7,   19.9,
       "March quarter 1...", "Central Coast",      279,       149,      24.2,   2.93,
         "March quarter 1...", "New South Wales",      170,       143,      99.8,   11.7,
              "March quarter 1...", "Hunter",      329,       266,      69.2,   10.8,
  "March quarter 1...", "New England Nort..",      115,       143,      60.3,   11.7,
     "March quarter 1...", "North Coast NSW",      828,       416,      55.4,   42.4,
         "March quarter 1...", "Outback NSW",     24.5,      21.3,      48.7,   2.07,
            "March quarter 1...", "Victoria",     46.5,      71.8,      82.4,   14.6
  )

states <- c("New South Wales", "Victoria", "Queensland", "South Australia",
            "Western Australia", "Tasmania", "Nothern Territory", "ACT")
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `case_when`, the type of the column is determined by the first case.
A dataframe column has only one type:

```
df <- data.frame(region = "NSW")
df %>% mutate(state = case_when(region == "Other" ~ "character",
                                T ~ NA_real_))

# Case 2 (`region == "" ~ 1`) must be a two-sided formula, not a double vector

# This works :
df %>% mutate(state = case_when(region == "Other" ~ "character",
                                T ~ NA_character_))

  region state
1    NSW  <NA>
```